# How to enable date_nanos function in ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I need to enable date_nanos support in ELK but fail.

I use docker to bring up elastic + kibana + filebeat.
And the version of Elastic is 7.9.0.

I set up a template of filebeat, which is just copied from original fields.yml and I only change the type of date to "date_nanos" as below.

```
- key: ecs
  title: ECS
  description: ECS Fields.
  fields:
  - name: '@timestamp'
    level: core
    required: true
    type: date_nanos
...
```

Then I have enabled the debug log of filebeat and the log says the mapping is loaded to elastic:

```
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2020-09-03T09:25:02.360Z","caller":"template/load.go:109","message":"Try loading template filebeat-7.9.0 to Elasticsearch"},
{"level":"debug","timestamp":"2020-09-03T09:25:02.364Z","logger":"esclientleg","caller":"eslegclient/connection.go:364","message":"PUT http://elasticsearch:9200/_template/filebeat-7.9.0  map[index_patterns:[filebeat-7.9.0-*] mappings:{\"_meta\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"version\":\"7.9.0\"},\"date_detection\":false,\"dynamic_templates\":[{\"labels\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"labels.*\"}},{\"container.labels\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"container.labels.*\"}},{\"dns.answers\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"dns.answers.*\"}},{\"log.syslog\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"log.syslog.*\"}},{\"network.inner\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"network.inner.*\"}},{\"observer.egress\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"observer.egress.*\"}},{\"observer.ingress\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"observer.ingress.*\"}},{\"fields\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"fields.*\"}},{\"docker.container.labels\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"docker.container.labels.*\"}},{\"kubernetes.labels.*\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"*\",\"path_match\":\"kubernetes.labels.*\"}},{\"kubernetes.annotations.*\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"*\",\"path_match\":\"kubernetes.annotations.*\"}},{\"docker.attrs\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"docker.attrs.*\"}},{\"kibana.log.meta\":{\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"path_match\":\"kibana.log.meta.*\"}},{\"strings_as_keyword\":{\"mapping\":{\"ignore_above\":1024,\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\"}}],\"properties\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"type\":\"date_nanos\"},\"agent\":{\"properties\":{\"ephemeral_id\":{\"ignore_above\":1024,\"type\":\"keyword\"},
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2020-09-03T09:25:02.846Z","caller":"template/load.go:101","message":"template with name 'filebeat-7.9.0' loaded."},
```

I can see the date_nanos setting in the log string:

```
"properties\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"type\":\"date_nanos\"},
```

But at last the "Type" of date in Kibana still shows "date" not "date_nanos"
[image]

Is there anything else I can do to enable date_nanos support ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` Type showing in the index pattern is not the same as the `date_nanos` type in your index mapping. The `Date` type in the index pattern is more intended for formatting purposes.

Kibana supports `date_nanos` [since version 7.3](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/36111).

So you're good to go already, nothing to be changed.

Comment: But the @timestamp field in kibana was truncated to "@timestamp": "2020-09-03T14:43:16.775Z", while the log content is "@timestamp":"2020-09-03T22:43:16.775626738+08:00".